# Sharing object among threads vs Creating the object for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am required to make a client-server application as my project submission for university finals.

I have figured out how I would be writing the server but I am kinda confused with this situation I am facing.

So the server is said to support only one defined *protocol* (represented by a `Protocol` interface) and would serve to the clients that speaks using that rule only. To test the functionality of the server, I have wrote an implementation that supports the HTTP Protocol so that I can quickly test the server from browser, but there is one thing that is really confusing me.

I have defined the server as:

```
public interface Server {

    // Methods...

    public void start() throws Exception;

    public Protocol getProtocol();

}
```

The base implementation of server does this:

```
public class StandardServer implements Server {

    /* Implementations */

    public synchronized final void start() throws Exception {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                // Use the protocol to handle the request
                getProtocol().handshake(socket);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused that is it really required to do this, as I am certain that there are better ways to do this.

What I have considered so far is:

- Synchronize the `getProtocol()` method.
- Make the implementation of `Protocol` a thread and then use it to handle requests.
- Spawn a thread when the client connects and pass-in the protocol object to that thread.

What would be the good ways to do this, considering that the server would be getting a decent amount of requests per second?

Any source code help/reference would be highly appreciated.

---

### P.S:

- I am ***not*** implementing an HTTP Server.
- There would be multiple implementations of `Server`

Comment: So, the server is supposed to support only one protocol, but you feel the need to define a Protocol abstraction, and to define a method allowing to change the protocol? Isn't that completely contradictory? And why is there a Server interface? Do you plan to have several implementations of Server? Why is the start method synchronized? Are there multiple threads starting the same server concurrently? This looks like over-engineering. Keep things simple.

Comment: Java has plenty of support to create web services, over well-tested, scalable web containers and APIs. Why are you reimplementing a HTTP server?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks I was about to do a blunder. By the way that project is just started. And yes, there would be multiple server implementation that would be loaded using a bootstrap classloader. But I think that I should really remove that `setProtocol()` method.

Comment: @JBNizet I am not actually implementing a HTTP Server, I have implemented an HTTP Protocol. This server would also be using a different protocol that I think I would define when I develop the client.